# Issue with Chrome AutoFill option

Tags: apex, visualforce, chrome

I got a form in which if we use chrome autofill to fill the fields, all of my apex get Methods are calling after form fields are filled with chrome autofill data.

Is there a way to stop it?

Comment: You want to stop the autofill?

Comment: No. I want to stop the action that is called if we use chrome Auto Fill @SarojBera